# Native private methods in Node.js

Tags: javascript, class, methods, private

I run code from MDN example (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_methods)

```
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 'hello world';
  }

  getPrivateMessage() {
    return this.#privateMethod();
  }
}

const instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
console.log(instance.getPrivateMessage());
// hello world
```

in Node.js 14 and got error:

```
  #privateMethod() {
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('
```

MDN contains info that private class methods are available from  Node.js 12.0.0
Private fields works fine. I need same private methods.
"use strict" turn on/off does not affect the error.
Is there a way to make the documentation example work in Node.js?

Comment: Perhaps they have it wrong - according to https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/ the private class fields have `?` for Node 12, though available in Node 14.6 and later - exactly what version of Node are you running

Comment: I have checked in Node v18.9.0 - the error remains

Comment: @M.Onyshchuk works fine in Node v14 and up.

Comment: You are wrong @M.Onyshchuk - it works fine in 18.9 and 16.17 for that matter

Comment: I'm confused with nvm. Checked again: in v14.5 the error remains in v14.6 works fine. I`m so sorry.